# Can't center header image with CSS no matter what

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I am using a theme to which I have added an image header (with our logo). I have called this image "https://www.londonim.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/logo.jpg".  the website address is https://londonim.co.il - it is in Hebrew (regardless).

The div in which "logo.jpg" is situated is inheriting some display from the there (i think "block"), and I would very much like it to be centered.

In order to try and center it i have used margins of 25% but it would not keep its central alignment when displayed in bigger screens (unless in full screen mode). 
when i temper with the wrapper's display property it generally disappears or loses the alignment altogether. Any thoughts please?

theme header:

```
<div class="cutewp-container" id="cutewp-header" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" role="banner">
    <div class="cutewp-head-content clearfix" id="cutewp-head-content">
        <div class="cutewp-outer-wrapper">
            <div class="cutewp-header-inside clearfix">
                <div id="cutewp-logo">
                    <div class="site-branding">
                        <a href="https://www.londonim.co.il/" rel="home" class="cutewp-logo-img-link">
                            <img src="https://www.londonim.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/logo.jpg" alt="" class="cutewp-logo-img">
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

my tweaks:

```
/* homepage tweaks */
.cutewp-main-wrapper {
    position:relative!important; 
    margin-left:12.5%;
    margin-right:12.5%; 
}

#cutewp-logo {
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}


#cutewp-primary-navigation {
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}

#cutewp-header {
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.menu-main-container {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to:

```
#cutewp-logo {
  margin-left:25%;//delete this
  margin-right:25%;//delete this
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;//delete this
  width: 100vw;//add this
}
```

The element isn't centering because it doesn't occupy the full width of the screen therefore has no reference on to be centered to

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear out a few of those `margin-left` and `margin-right`

**CHANGE**

```
#cutewp-logo {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 41%;
}

.cutewp-main-wrapper {
    position: relative!important;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    #cutewp-header {
        margin-left: 25%;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .cutewp-content-wrapper {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
}
```

**TO**

```
#cutewp-logo {
    margin: auto;
}

.cutewp-main-wrapper {
    position: relative!important;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    #cutewp-header {
        background-color: white;
    }
    .cutewp-content-wrapper {
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

This will fix the issue on both your desktop and mobile view.

Comment: Thanks @ScottieG - this actually did the trick. guess it's a case of you can't see the forest for the trees! many thanks